# Azure Cosmos DB: is it always necessary to check for HasMoreResults?

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

All examples for querying `Azure Cosmos DB` with .NET C# check `FeedIterator<T>.HasMoreResults` before calling `FeedIterator<T>.ReadNextAsync()`.

Considering that the default `MaxItemCount` is 100, and knowing for a fact that the query will return fewer items than 100, is it necessary to check for `HasMoreResults`?

Consider this example, which returns an integer:

```
var query = container.GetItemQueryIterator<int>("SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c");
int count = (await query.ReadNextAsync()).SingleOrDefault();
```

Is it necessary to check for `HasMoreResults`?

Comment: I believe so. In the general case, a query may return results from one partition at a time.

Comment: You gain nothing but not checking it. And would at least prevent you from having to change your code and redeploy if it ever did grow beyond what you are expecting today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your query can yield/terminate sooner, like the aggregations, then probably there is no more pages and HasMoreResults = false.

But the reason to always check HasMoreResults is because, in most cases, the SDK prefetches the next pages in memory while you are consuming the current one. If you don't drain all the pages, then these objects stay in memory. With time, memory footprint might increase (until eventually they get garbage collected but that can also consume CPU).

In cross-partition queries, it is common to see users make wrong assumptions, like, assuming all results of the query will be in 1 page (the first) and that can be true depending on which physical partition the data is stored, and it is very common in such cases users complaining that they had some code running for some time perfectly fine and then suddenly it stopped working (their data is now on another partition and not returning in the first page).

In some cases, the service might need to yield due to execution time going over the max time.

So, to avoid all these pitfalls (and others), the general recommendation is to loop until HasMoreResults = false. You won't be iterating more than it is required for each query, sometimes it will be one page, sometimes it might be more.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/pagination#understanding-query-executions

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, we need to perform `HasMoreResults` Boolean check on DocumentClient object. If `HasMoreResults` is true then we can get more records by calling `ExecuteNext` method.

Also supporting comment by Mark Brown, it is best practice to check for `HasMoreResults`.

For managing results returned from quires Cosmosdb uses a continuation strategy. Each query submitted to Cosmos Db will have `MaxItemCount` Limit attribute and default limit value is 100.

The response of requests exceeding the MaxItemCount will get paginated and in response header continuation token will be present, which shows first partial page is returned and more records are available. Next pages can be retrieved by passing continuation token to subsequent calls.